# Tensorflow/Keras: Error when calculating intermediate layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a network `network`, which is already trained and written with `tensorflow`. In a later step of my computation I want to `predict` the intermediate layer outputs of said network. For that I followed [the instructions of the Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

My code for creating the intermediate layer looks as follows:

```
intermediate_layer = tf.keras.Model(inputs=network.input,
                                    outputs=network.layers[some_layer].output)
data = load_data()
y = intermediate_layer.predict(data)  # <-- The error occurs here
```

For this code, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1478, in predict
  self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 363, in predict_loop
  batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 2897, in __call__
  fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1454, in __call__
  self._session._session, self._handle, args, status, None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
  c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv1/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv1/kernel)
     [[Node: conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv1/kernel)]]
     [[Node: max_pooling2d/MaxPool/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_37_max_pooling2d/MaxPool", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

The previous network is already compiled and runs perfectly fine.

Did anyone face a similar issue and can me provide with a solution? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You created new model using an existing architecture, but you didn't compile it from the looks of it

Comment: There is no need to compile for predict.

Comment: Are you sure you loaded the network with `tf.keras` and not with `keras`? (You must use one single library, you can't mix `keras` with `tf.keras`.

Comment: Recently, some versions have been asking for you to initialize vars, and that can be done with `network.predict(data[:1])`, then you try to build the and use the submodel.

Comment: I load my model with `tensorflow.keras` in both cases. Though, the optimizer and loss of `network` consisting partly of `keras` code (not written by me and I would be glad to keep the original code as much as possible). Does this impose a problem?

Comment: Are you mixing up tf.keras layer with keras layer? If the original model is built up using keras then using tf.keras for next model will through error.